# Enabling & Disabling tree mesh collider when player is close to & away from trees

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, unityscript

I made a forest scene, and basically it's full of trees (tree density = max), but the trees can be easily walked through. So I added mesh collider to each of the trees, and when I press play, the game becomes so slow that fps is less than 10.

Does Unity have a way to disable trees' mesh collider that is 10 units (radius of a hemisphere) away from the player and enable it when player comes closer to it?

`C#` and `UnityScript` are acceptable when scripting is required.

Answer (score 2):

Never use `MeshCollider` in Unity. Instead use `CapsuleCollider` or `BoxCollider`.
For your problem, if you just want the tree to not be walked through, I suggest use distance, like this:

```
if(Vector3.Distance(person.position,Tree.position) < (Tree.radius + person.radius)) {
    //can't pass
}
```

I believe it will be faster than collider.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to add a `CapsuleCollider` instead of a `MeshCollider`. This will improve your fps to a great extent. Otherwise you will have to do it manually by maintaining a list all renderers or colliders and turn them on and off according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it,First you have to find Distance between Your Player and Trees by vector3.distance check unity doc for vector3.distance and when your player come closer to tree then you find your Trees by gameobject.find and enable and disable your gameobject like:

```
public class EnableComponents : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Light myLight;


    void Start ()
    {
        myLight = GetComponent<Light>();
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;
        }
    }
}
```